# Ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

Пытался написать сортировку списка с использованием рекурсии, начала вылезать ошибка `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` после добавления рекурсии функции(до этого для тестов использовал списки из трех элементов - рекурсия была не нужна).

```py
def a(mas):
    menshe = []
    bolshe = []
    sorted = []
    if len(mas) <= 2:
        return mas
    else:
        a = int(len(mas) // 2)
        vibor = mas[a]
        del mas[a]
        if len(mas) == 2:
            for i in mas:
                if i < vibor:
                    menshe.append(i)
                else:
                    bolshe.append(i)
            sorted.append(menshe)
            sorted.append(vibor)
            sorted.append(bolshe)
            print(sorted)
        else:
            a(mas)
```

Сорри за говно код, только учусь)

Comment: Что вы ожидали от программы, написав `a(mas)`?

Comment: Чтобы снова запустилась данная функция, но уже с новым списком mas, появившемся при удалении элемента vibor

Comment: Но вы написали `a = int(` значит `a` это не функция, а число

Comment: Ааа, я использовал а как название фунцкии, и потом и как переменную... Из-за этого вылезала данная ошибка. Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!

Comment: Вот поэтому и рекомендуется сразу приучать себя делать нормальные значащие имена )

Comment: @GovnoKoder Это в общем одна из типичных ошибок начинающих писать на питоне из-за того, что Питон позволяет спокойно использовать одни и те же имена для совершенно разных сущностей внутри одного кода и даже предупреждения не выдаёт.

Answer (score 2):

Функция названа также, как и внутренняя переменная.

Таким образом, когда в последней строке вы "вызываете" `a(mas)` для программы в этот момент `a` уже переназначено и там число (из строки `a = int(len(mas) // 2)`).

Для того чтобы такие ошибки не возникали, пожалуйста прочитайте [соглашения по форматированию кода](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) и не используйте короткие `a`, `b`, `i`, `j`, `k` и прочие названия, а используйте осмысленные имена переменных и функций. Для функций обычно используют глагол или описание действия.